# How do I can integrate Power BI report with my custom application?

Tags: powerbi, integration, power-bi-report-server

I am new to this technology. I need to integrate the Power BI report with my application. I am following this link but have not got any successful response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report

Any help please most welcome.

Comment: This link is not related to the embedding. Check [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app) instead.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov  the link provides APIs. Does not it use for integration?
I have an ERPNext application where i need to integrate.

Comment: Then you have to explain what "integrate the Power BI report with my application" means.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov I have an ERPNext application. In one of the forms/pages, I have a button and on click of that button, it should open the PowerBi report that is developed by my team.